# How do array filter function work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Here is piece of code I am trying to fully understand:

```
const words = ['chair', 'music', 'pillow', 'brick', 'pen', 'door']; 
 
const shortWords = words.filter(word => {
  return word.length < 6;
});
```

My current assumption is that shortWords is a function that is having another function passed in as a parameter.

So shortWords is to use .filter on the words array. The argument (which is also a function?) thats passed into the shortWords function is supposed to return all words with a length less than 6 letters from the array.

Is my understaning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: `shortWords` is the *array* returned from the call to `.filter()`

Comment: _"My current assumption is that shortWords is a function that is having another function passed in as a parameter"_ - no. It is a _variable_, that gets the return value of the method call `words.filter(...)` assigned to it. _That_ method gets a function passed as parameter, this is commonly known as a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct except the fact that `shortWords` is a variable that stores an array returned by .filter function.

The types of `words` is an array.

`const words = ['chair', 'music', 'pillow', 'brick', 'pen', 'door'];`

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method/function that allows you to loop through the array. As the name suggests, it is used to filter the array and create a new array.

Array.filter accepts a function as a parameter. In your provided snippet you have passed an arrow function as a parameter inside the filter method.

This is similar to the following code with simple function:

```
function filterFunctionAsParam(word) {
  return word.length < 6;
}
const shortWords = words.filter(filterFunctionAsParam);
```

The filter method does not change the array it acts upon. That is it does not mutate words array. The value of words array does not change. Rather it returns a filtered array. `shortWords` is that filtered array.

For each array element, if the condition returned by the filterFunctionAsParam is true, the element is returned by the filter function.

This can also be achieved with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods.

Answer (score 0):

> My current assumption is that shortWords is a function that is having another function passed in as a parameter.

No, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a function which has another function passed to it as a parameter.

It operates on an array, and calls the passed-in function on each element in the array - if it returns true then that array item is included in the result of calling `filter`.